# VPN through Public Wifi

Tags: vpn

Here's the scenario:

- I am at a public cafe which offers free WIFI
- I enabled VPN and I can connect / visit our company's wiki

My question is if I surf the Internet or check my gmail, would the traffic go through the VPN tunnel?

If yes, how do you prove it?
If no, how can you safely surf the Internet / check your gmail through a public WIFI?

Answer (score 7):

Read the routing table of your OS (while connected) and check whether the "default gateway" or "default route" belongs to the cafe or to your company's network.

**Windows:**

```
route print
netsh interface ip show route
netsh interf ipv6 show route
```

**Linux:**

```
ip route
ip -6 route
route
```

**BSDs:**

```
route
```

**All of the above:**

```
netstat -r
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did what you suggested and it belongs to the cafe.
So how would I change all my Internet traffic such that it uses the VPN tunnel when I enable my VPN?

Comment: That depends somewhat on the OS and the VPN software used.